# How to add Days to DATE using criteria API?

Tags: postgresql, date, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I would like to filter out deliveryMethods that cannot fulfil orders before the deadline that is specified by the customer. DeliveryMethod has a deliveryDeadlineAmount (int) field that show how many days do they need to prepare an order.

This is what I have written so far:

```
...

DateTime deadlineByCustomer = LocalDate.now().plusDays(2);

...

Join<Site, DeliveryMethod> deliveryMethod = site.join(Site.Fields.deliveryMethods, JoinType.INNER);

if (deadlineByCustomer != null) {
    Predicate deliveryMethodCanSatisfyDeadline = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
           criteriaBuilder.function("DATEADD", LocalDate.class,
                   criteriaBuilder.literal(TemporalUnit.DAY),
                   deliveryMethod.get(DeliveryMethod.Fields.deliveryDeadlineAmount),
                   criteriaBuilder.literal(LocalDate.now())
           ),
            criteriaBuilder.literal(deadlineByCustomer));
    predicates.add(deliveryMethodCanSatisfyDeadline);
}

...
```

I get this error: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.BasicSqmPathSource.getSqmPathType()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmLiteral.getNodeType()" is null

Previously I tried to use

```
criteriaBuilder.literal("day")
```

instead of

```
criteriaBuilder.literal(TemporalUnit.DAY)
```

But then I got this error: Parameter 1 of function timestampadd() has type TEMPORAL_UNIT, but argument is of type java.lang.Object

I dont understand why does it want to call timestampadd if I want to call a native SQL function "DATEADD".

I am using postgreSQL and Hibernate.

Comment: There is no `DATEADD()` function in Postgres. You can just add an integer to a `date` data type to get the resulting date. See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: I tried that as well with criteriaBuilder.sum but I am having trouble with that as well. Could you give me a working code example where you add current DateTime and deliveryMethod.get(DeliveryMethod.Fields.deliveryDeadlineAmount)?

Comment: Use +1 ,or whatever number of days you need, It is all you need

Comment: I have tried it every possible way I could. But I am having problems with that because I dont know how it is possible to add a LocalDate with an Expression. This is why I have asked for a code example.